# Create a matlab debugger breakpoint and enter debugger in .m file code

Tags: matlab, debugging

How can I create a matlab debugger breakpoint on the current line of a .m matlab file, cause matlab to enter the debugger at that point? I.e., pause the current code execution and drop into the debugger?

This would help me because I edit matlab files in an external editor. Wen I save a file, matlab clears any breakpoints I have set in that file. I have tried:

```
dbstop at [current_file.m]
```

which does not work because it sets breakpoint at the first line in the file.

As an example, in *python*, this could be done by:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keyboard` to stop at a certain point in the code.
The only problem is that it requires editing the code each time you want to add\remove a breakpoint

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`dbstop`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) to stop at a specific line:

```
dbstop in FILESPEC at LINENO
```

`help dbstop` gives you all the options.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but for my purposes -- debugging code -- it's not robust, because if I edit the file above that line then the line number will be wrong. Then the break point will be above line with `dbstop`, and won't be triggered.